# Check and reset Display Scale & Layout in Windows using VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net

I developed a screen casting software for Windows using VB.NET (VS 2019), which allow users to capture a specific region (named pic) in the window. The capture process works fine except when a user change Scale and layout in Display settings, as shown in the screenshot below. 
is there any way to check or reset the user's Scale & layout using VB.NET?
Here is the code I use to define the area I need to capture:

```
capturer.CaptureRectTop = picTop
capturer.CaptureRectLeft = picLeft
capturer.CaptureRectWidth = pic.Width
capturer.CaptureRectHeight = pic.Height
```

[image: Display Scale & Layout in Windows]

Comment: Make your application DPI-aware and you won't have to work around it.

Comment: Thank you appreciated: based in your comment @IInspectable I found the solution at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms